# How do different browsers behave upon X-UA-Compatible tag?

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, x-ua-compatible, ie-compatibility-mode

I'm building a website, and I'm using IE9 to test it (because I have to :( ). Recently I found out that IE is running on compatibility mode for IE7 which is ruining some of my layout.
To fix this I'm using the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` tag.

So my question is, how do other browsers (Chrome, Firefox, etc...) behave upon this tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This meta tag is only used within Internet Explorer so will have no impact on any other browser.